# Skip new Ajax requests for x seconds

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, web, server

I have an infinite loop in which **multiple** QR markers are being detected from a live video feed. I want the QR code IDs being sent to the server via ajax. This is how I do it:

```
    while (true) {
        var markers = detect(imageData);

        $.ajax({
          url: '/upload',
          data: { QRCodes: markers.id },
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          },
          error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
    }
```

The problem with this approach is a bottleneck in the ajax requests. When for example, a QR code with an id "12" is detected, it rapidly posts "12 12 12 12 12...", which is too fast for ajax to send to the server. Whenever new QR codes are detected it causes a huge delay until the most recent QR marker is being received on the server.

Thus, I would ajax to only accept a new request every 0.2 seconds. Meanwhile, all other requests outside of this "delay" should be just ignored. Or, instead of a delay I like the ajax to only send the newest QR marker (**Last in First Out**).

EDIT:

We simply have to implement a "setInterval" and save the marker IDs in a global var.

```
var allMarkers = -1;

window.onload = onLoad;  // In this function the "allMarkers" is being updated in the while loop

setInterval(function() { 
  $.ajax({
    url: '/navigator_upload',
    data: { QRCodes: allMarkers },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}, 1000 * 60 * 0.02); // Fire ajax every 2 seconds with updated value
```

Comment: You should probably look for ```document.setInterval()```
Have a global variable array, with the ids of the qrcodes, and inside your delayed function, sort that array and get the latest value.

Comment: so you mean have the ajax part outside of the while loop and implement a setInternval? hmm.. I will try I out, thanks!

Comment: may I ask why you constantly "detect()" ? Can't you just hook a "onchange" event ?

Comment: @Loïc there is no such thing as `document.setInterval`, I assume you're referring to the global function `setInterval` (which you could also access as `window.setInterval`.

Comment: @Loïc the "markers" array contains all detected QR codes from a single image frame. A "onchange" event would fire equally fast because if a QR code is not detected for 1ms, the values of the array changes again. Besides, this code is from a library (see aruco.js).

Comment: @Loïc BTW: im not planning to sort the array and get latest value. the array is not a history of all markers recorded. it already contains the newest qr markers detected from an image frame

Comment: then yes, setInterval is perfect.
Run your exact function every 0.2 secs instead of while true and you should be fine.

Comment: Yep it worked really well :-) many thanks